# How do i iterate and get value of each checkbox when checked in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

I can only get the value of the first value in the checkbox.
I want to iterate through the rows in the table and get all the e.file_id in each checkbox (when checked), put into an array and send it to the Controller.
im using Spring MVC.

this is my javascript

```
<script>
    var multipleFiles = [];
    
    function selectMultipleFilesToDL() {
        var cbCheck = document.getElementById("selectedFile");
        var table = document.getElementById('downloadTable');
        
        for (var i = 1; i< table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j<i; j++) {
                if (cbCheck.checked==true) { 
                    console.log("cbCheck value is " + cbCheck.value);
                    multipleFiles.push(cbCheck.value);          
                }
           }  
        }
        console.log("Array size " + multipleFiles.length);
        console.log("Array values " + multipleFiles);
};
```

this is my HTML table

```
<table id="downloadTable" class="downloadTable"
    style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; column-width: 20px;">
    <tr style="text-align: center">
        <th style="width: 5%">id</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">User ID</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">File ID</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">File Data</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">File Name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Select</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">File Type</th>
    </tr>


    <c:forEach items="${listfiles}" var="e">
        <tr style="text-align: left;">
            <td style="text-align: center">${e.id}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">${e.user_id}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">${e.file_id}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                <button
                    onClick="window.location='/SpringWithMyBatis/startDownload?file_id=${e.file_id}'">
                    Download</button>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center">${e.file_name}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox"
                class="selectedFile" name="selectedFile" id="selectedFile"
                value="'${e.file_id}"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center">${e.file_type}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: The code could be simplified by using [getSelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the [:checked pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [yogi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943435/yogi), i did this and it works

```
var fileCheck = document.querySelectorAll(".selectedFile");
        fileCheck.forEach((e) => {
            if (e.checked) {
                multipleFiles.push(e.value);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Change the selector to ".downloadTable .selectedFile:checked" and then you may remove the if statement.  The query will only return the checked inputs.